# How to prevent backbone model to collection event propagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

How do I prevent Backbone Model events from propagating to Backbone Collections?

Edit:

Let's say I have something like the following, where CollectionView contains a collection of MyModels...

```
var CollectionView = Backbone.Collection.Extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.on("change", doStuff);
    }
});

var ModelView = Backbone.View.Extend({ 
    initialize: function() {
        this.model = new MyModel();
        this.model.on( "change", doStuff );
        this.model.fetch();
    }
});
```

If in a special case I did not want the "change" event to propagate up to the collection after fetch completes, I am wondering if there is any way to stop it.

Thanks

Comment: Models don't fire the reset event, could you expand on your question? Specifically what code are you running that is firing the event you don't want to propagate?

Comment: To @Tomdarkness's point, the code you've shown is the event binding. What is actually triggering the event? (I think this is a good question, because the answer is not apparent in the docs AFAIK.)

Comment: I wasn't aware that models did not fire the reset event -- good to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To prevent a model from firing a change event:

```
model.set(attrs, {silent: true});
```

This may not be what you want, though, because this will also prevent the model's change event from firing.

Collections pass through all model events, but what you can do is pass extra options which will also get passed through:

```
model.set(attrs, {dontBubble: true});
```

And in your CollectionView:

```
var CollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  this.initialize = function() {
    this.collection.on('change', doStuff, this);
  },
  this.doStuff = function(model, collection, options) {
    if (options.dontBubble) {
      return;
    }
    // Do some stuff.
  }
});
```

Granted, it's a little ugly, but it's one way to go about it.